# Java chat-commands

Tags: java, network-programming, chat, instant-messaging

I was making a chat program in Java (Java Socket) and I was thinking about making build-in-commands! For and example; you write "date" and it will show the date! Here I have maked one but it dosen't work. It shows only the "else" satement!

```
            streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();       //Reading the object.. and storing it in a variable...
            if(streamChat.equals("date")){
                Date date = new Date();
                showMess("\n " + date);

            }else{
                showMess("\n " + streamChat);
            }
```

Comment: What is `inputdata`? What does `readObject` do? Are you sure you don't send newlines or spaces? If you're using TCP, are you sure you receive the whole line of input in a single receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple... I see that `streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();` is INPUT from the client. So only if the client send "date" you will get the date. Remove if statement to another place in the output area.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little to less. Try trim() on your string or contains instead of equals.

```
  streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();      
  streamChat = streamChat.trim();
  if(streamChat.equals("date")) { ...
```

or

```
streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();     
if(streamChat.contains("date")) { ...
```

but as I said you provided to less information. Could you write something about how are you getting input from user?

Comment: Please give a example